# prepared statements using psycopg

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, prepared-statement, psycopg

I'm a beginner at python. We use this code to execute SQL commands.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (100, "abcdef"))
```

I wonder is this prepared statement or just a client side quoting?

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775497/psycopg-get-formatted-sql-instead-of-executing

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it does not, not for psycopg2 at least.  The "Prepare" in the docs refers to a "PREPARE TRANSACTION" which is entirely different than a prepared statement.

You can emulate a prepared statement, by overriding the methods or executing extra statements, however. See: [An example of psycopg2 cursor supporting prepared statements](https://gist.github.com/dvarrazzo/3797445)

Please see: [relevant blog entry for psycopg.](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2012/10/01/prepared-statements-psycopg/)

More information:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html

Answer (score 0):

`psycopg` does support prepared statements starting with version 3:

https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/prepare.html#prepared-statements

> A query is prepared automatically after it is executed more than prepare_threshold times on a connection.

Answer (score -8):

According to [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html) the execute method will "Prepare and execute a database operation (query or command).". So yes, it is a prepared statement.

Comment: Actually it currently does not. The "Prepare" in this documentation refers to a "PREPARE TRANSACTION" call required for two-phase commit, not a precompiled SQL statement.