# pymssql - Get formatted sql instead of executing

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql

See cousin post: [psycopg - Get formatted sql instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775497/psycopg-get-formatted-sql-instead-of-executing)

I need to transition some code from Postgres to MS SQL Server. I have been using psycopg2 in Python to do all database calls. I have found a simlar library in pymssql that actually has a very similar API.

One thing that is missing is the `mogrify` call. In short, `mogrify` prevents SQL injection but does so without executing. Great for building up a SQL string.

Is there a call that is similar to the `mogrify` call in pymssql? If not, is there anohter Python library that does have a mogrify-like call? If I cannot find anything, I will transition my code to use the `execute`/`executemany` calls, but I'd prefer to avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `substitute_params` is exported in the _mssql module.  Example usage:

```
>>> import pymssql
>>> print pymssql._mssql.substitute_params("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a = %s", ("quoted ' string",))
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a = 'quoted '' string'
```